# Location Accuracy on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it somehow possible to get the location accuracy?

I know how to get the location, but I would like to know the location accuracy radius in meters, for example.

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When You use class Geolocator:

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
var acc=geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters;
```

From docs:

*DesiredAccuracyInMeters*

> Windows Phone only. Gets or sets the desired accuracy in meters for data returned from the location service.

More information about class: [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.aspx)

Comment: Is this how i set a desired accuracy?

Comment: I am using geolocator to get the longitude and latitude, but i can not get the accuracy. I can only set the desired accuracy and of course it returns the used value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a position as a Geoposition you can do this

```
Geoposition MyGeoPosition
...
double acc = MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Accuracy;
```

Accuracy is returned in meters.